# supabase auth-helpers with auth-ui, how to hide email/password when using social

Tags: node.js, sveltekit, supabase

When setting social login, there doesn't seem to be a way to hide the email/password boxes.

```
<Auth
            supabaseClient={data.supabase}
            view="sign_in"
            providers={['google']}
            redirectTo={`${data.url}/logging-in?redirect=/`}
            showLinks={false}
            appearance={{ theme: ThemeSupa, style: { input: 'color: #fff' } }}
            theme="dark"
        />
```

Is there a way to either set the parameter or expose the module so that it's editable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide email/password by passing `onlyThirdPartyProviders={true}` to the `Auth` component. Or alternatively if you are using the latest version of the auth-ui you should be able to import the `SocialAuth` component.

Comment: Fab, thank you.

The demo on the docs is incorrect, but 'onlyThirdPartyProviders={true}' works as expected.

I can't find any docs for using just the 'SocialAuth' component, or get it working.

Comment: It works! Thank you